# ESLint disable specific rule for line break

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have the following code:

```
import {
  reactSelectStyleCustom,
  reactSelectStyleDefault,
} from '~/helper/const'
```

I need to change a specific ESLint rule to get something like this:

```
import { reactSelectStyleCustom, reactSelectStyleDefault } from '~/helper/const'
```

I've tried adding the "linebreak-style" at .eslintrc.json but didn't work

```
"rules": {
  "linebreak-style": 0,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This triggers the ["object-curly-spacing"](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-spacing) lint, so ignore it:

```
"rules": {
  "object-curly-spacing": "off",
}
```